# Midedlware class is not working in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have a laravel application in this application i have following function for login user

```
     public function login() {
    try {
        $inputs = Input::except('_token');
        $validator = Validator::make($inputs, User::$login);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Please Enter Valid Credentials');
        } else {
            $respones = \UserHelper::processLogin($inputs);
            if ($respones) {

                return Redirect::to('/dashboard')->with('success_message', 'Welcome to Tressly Admin Dashboard');
            } else {
                return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Please Enter Valid Information ');
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return CommonHelper::AdminExceptions($ex);
    }
}
```

Now as user logout and presses the back button , browser show previous page as it is present in cache. Now on this page as user tries to access any protected route application It shows following error 
I want to redirect it to '/'( home route)as logged out user tries to acess any protect routes following error comes

```
   Class App\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate does not exist
```

I have made a custom Authentication Middle , handle function of the middleware is

```
      public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

I have also registered it in kernal.php in $routeMiddleware like

```
   'authAdmin' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,
```

and protected my route like

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'authAdmin'], function () {
      ///routes 
   });
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
    'authAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,
```

Instead of

```
   'authAdmin' =>\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,
```

I hope it it will work

Comment: class auth was not working . I have use Auth in AdminAuthenticate , 
Thanks man it is working now. u save my day.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you made a custom middleware class that does exactly the same thing as the already present 'auth' middleware?

RedirectifAuthenticated.php does this;

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#protecting-routes